# How to specify a destination folder with MSDeploy

Tags: msdeploy

I have MSDeploy successfully deploying a web package zip file to a remote IIS website using a command like this

```
MyDeployCommand.deploy.cmd /T /M:https://MyServer:8172/msdeploy.axd -allowUntrusted   /U:Username /P:Password /A:Basic "-setParam:name='IIS Web Application Name',value='My Website Name'"
```

Although this works, it defaults to the current directory that the website is pointing to. I'd like to change the physical path. I've tried a number of parameters with no success and was wondering if this is even possible to do.

Thanks to chief7 for pointing out the appcmd, which on the target works eg

```
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set site /site.name:"My Website Name" /application[path='/'].virtualDirectory[path='/'].physicalPath:"C:\new\path"
```

However if I try the same thing on the remote machine eg

```
"%MSDeployPath%msdeploy.exe" -verb:sync -source:runCommand="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set site /site.name:;quot;My Website Name;quot; /application[path='/'].virtualDirectory[path='/'].physicalPath:;quot;C:\new\path;quot;",dontUseCommandExe=true -dest:auto
```

Its coming back with

Error: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002) which I assume is referring to the appcmd. I added

```
dontUseCommandExe=true
```

to get around the problem of it being called via cmd.exe

Answer (score 0):

You can extend the WebDeploy manifest to alter the site/app path with a RunCommand provider.

```
<runcommand path=&quot;%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set app /app.name:&amp;quot;Default Web Site/app12&amp;quot; /&#91;path=&#39;/&#39;&#93;.physicalPath:C:\temp\app12&quot; waitInterval=&quot;5000&quot;/>
```

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/06/28/webdeploymsdeploy-quick-tip-change-iis-siteapp-physical-path-with-msdeploy/

http://www.dotnetcatch.com/2016/05/19/extending-the-webdeploy-manifest/

The `appHostConfig` provider is also supposed to let you change the directory but this was easier.